# Is it possible to make a generic Realm Results Object?

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to replicate NSFetchedResults controller but with a Realm backing.  My problem is that with the RealmSwift framework, I cannot make a generic Results object.  It wants a specific type.

`var objects: Results<Object> = Realm().objects(Object)`

compiles, but crashes when the controller subclass is presented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your code even compiles as there are two assignments in that statement:

```
var objects = Results<Object> = Realm().objects(Object)
```

Calling `Realm().objects(Object)` returns a generic `Results`, specialized on `Object`, so `Results` generic.

Comment: jpsim, I have tried this, but I get the follow error: 'Object type 'Object' not persisted in Realm'

Comment: `Object` isn't a model class, but rather the class you must subclass in order to define your model. So if you have a model like `class MyModel: Object {}`, you could call `Realm().objects(MyModel)` to get all `MyModel` objects from the default Realm.